# Vim indent using "=" inserts 2 tabs

Tags: indentation

If I try to indent a code using visual mode or `ggVG=` vi automatically inserts 2 tabs instead of just 1.

for example:

```
// inside main
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    test += i;
}
```

changes to:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                int test = 2;
        }
```

There are two tabs before `for` and `int`. I want a single tab. I have set:

```
set noexpandtab
set tabstop=4
set softtabstop=0
set smartindent
```

is there any way to change the two tabs to one?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your 'shiftwidth' appears to still be set to the default value of 8. Try changing that to 4 to match your 'tabstop' setting:

```
:set shiftwidth=4
```

See

```
:help 'shiftwidth'
```